# Owin middleware did not call any api controller on production server

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, owin

I developed an api with OWIN authentication.
StartUp.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            Provider = new MyOAuthServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
```

In WebApi.Config

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

In MyOauthServerProvider

```
public class CRMnextOAuthServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        await Task.FromResult(context.Validated());
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        if (!IsAuthenticated(context.UserName, context.Password))
        {
            context.SetError(
                "invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("user_name", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string> ());
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);

        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
}
```

I use above code for owin set up. this code is running fine on my local IIS, Testing port, and one public IP(locally).

**Problem**
when i deployed it on production server, **i am able to access the token url**, but not any controller url. it shows below error on server:

[image]